# How do I get the path of a registered COM server in C#?

Tags: c#, com, typelib, com-server

Is there a nice way to programmatically get the path of a registered COM server in C#?

We have an out-of-process COM server (i.e., an exe-file) that we reference in our C# project; however we want to enforce that we run the COM server from a specific location, so we'd like to check the path of the registered exe-file before starting it. Is there a good way to do this, besides diving into the registry?

Comment: The registry usage is in fact documented, for example the LocalServer32 key: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683844.aspx

Comment: No, there is no nice way.  Just don't rely on an oracle when the server itself can trivially tell you.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you elaborate? Is there a default method that all COM servers must implement returning their location? Or do you mean that the OP should add such a method to their server (in case they can change its source code...)?

Answer (score 0):

The function [QueryPathOfRegTypeLib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221436(v=vs.85).aspx) does just that.

However, I did notice a strange quirk:

If I first register from one path on a per-user basis:

c:\Path1\comserver.exe /regserverperuser

and then register from another path on a system level basis:

c:\Path2\comserver.exe /regserver

Then QueryPathOfRegTypeLib returns c:\Path1\comserver.exe, but it is actually c:\Path2\comserver.exe which is started when you load the type library...